# React native debug logging stucks

Tags: android, debugging, react-native

I have a link in the back-end, so I fetch a post request to that link and receive a response. When I alert that response it gives a body init and body text in which I receive datas I need. Everything is good. But..
When I enable remote debugging and console.log that response, it gives body init and body blob (and both are empty). It stucks when I eneble debugging..
Thanks for attention ))
My code:

```
logIn = async (username, password) => {
// alert(`username : ${username}\n password : ${password}`);
let loginFormData = new FormData();

loginFormData.append('LoginForm[username]', username);
loginFormData.append('LoginForm[password]', password);
loginFormData.append('MacAddress', '111');
loginFormData.append('loginType', 'mobile');

try {
  fetch('http://192.168.2.115/araqich_client/general/default/logout', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: loginFormData
  });

  let request = fetch('http://192.168.2.115/araqich_client/general/default/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: loginFormData
  });

  let loginResponseJson = await request;

  if (loginResponseJson && loginResponseJson != null ) {
    // let loginResponse = JSON.parse(loginResponseJson._bodyInit);
    alert(JSON.stringify(loginResponseJson._bodyInit));
    let status = loginResponse.status;

    if (status) {
      let SyncFormData = new FormData();
      let accessToken = loginResponse.ACCESS_TOKEN;

      SyncFormData.append('ACCESS_TOKEN', accessToken);
      SyncFormData.append('MacAddress', '111');
      SyncFormData.append('loginType', 'mobile');

      let syncRequest = fetch('http://192.168.2.115/araqich_client/mobile/defaultA/syncAndroid', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: SyncFormData
      });

      let syncResponseJson = await syncRequest;

      if (syncResponseJson && syncResponseJson != null) {
        let syncResponse = JSON.parse(syncResponseJson._bodyInit);
        let status = syncResponse.status;

        if (!status) {
          alert('Sorry(( something went wrong...');
        } else {
          alert('Life is good)))');
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert('else1')
    }
  } else {
    alert('else')
  }
} catch (error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using console.log statements, I'd advise using your debugger.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you give an example? I think I actually use debugger, because withot that I'll not be able to see console.log's output ))

Comment: You're using your developer's console, but you're still likely not using your debugger. Go into your code and type `debugger` on its own line. This will create a breakpoint and will allow you to inspect variables, assuming you have remote debugging enabled.